# How to get the text in the previous element and do some maths

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following structure:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>first</td>
    <td class="price">__</td>
    <td><input type="text" class="quantity"></td>
    <td class="amount></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Inside the `<td class="price">` goes a value that is retrieved through AJAX function.

So I have this on my javascript file:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
    // alert('document ready');

    $("input.quantity").live("blur", function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        quantity = $this.val();
        price = $this.prev("td.price").text();
        alert(price);
        amount = quantity * price;
        $this.next("td.amount").html(amount);
    });
  });
});
```

but price returns nil (even price being loaded correctly thro my ajax function)

EDIT: This is the final code following all suggestions below. Thank you all!

```
$("input.quantity").live("blur", function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        quantity = parseInt($this.val()); // in this case, people can't buy a 1 item and a half for example.

        price = $this.parents("tr").find("td.price").text();
        price = parseFloat(price);  // price can have "cents"

        amount = quantity * price;
        amount = Number(amount).toFixed(2); // I should be able to see at least 2 first decimal digits from the amount.

        $this.parent().next("td.amount").html(amount);
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To get your previous / next elements you could use the following:**

```
parseInt($this.parent().prev("td.price").text());  //or parseFloat
```

**and**

```
parseInt($this.parent().next("td.amount").text()); //or parseFloat
```

**Full Code:**

```
jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("input.quantity").live("blur", function() {
        var $this = $(this);

        quantity = parseInt($this.val());
        alert("Quantity : " + quantity);

        price = parseInt($this.parent().prev("td.price").text());
        alert("Price : " + price);

        amount = quantity * price;
        $this.parent().next("td.amount").html(amount);
        alert("Amount : " + amount);
    });
});
```

[**Working Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rionmonster/hghBE/1/)

Comment: This is the most complete answer. Showing the both options parseFloat and parseInt. Also displays the calculated amount in the right place.

I made a few additions to this piece. Please take a look my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {
// alert('document ready');

$("input.quantity").live("blur", function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    quantity = $this.val();
    price = $this.parent().siblings("td.price").text();
    price=parseFloat(price);
    alert(price);
    amount = quantity * price;
    $this.parent().siblings("td.amount").html(amount);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: As a first answer, this works. I just changed parseInt to parseFloat since it's a price value. But fail on writing the amount on the td.amount tag. I've to put a parents() before next() function.

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the answer to reflect this, completely missed it.

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
price = $this.parents("tr").find("td.price").text();
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/Pn7mz/).

Answer (score 1):

This may be a datatype issue when doing your mulitplication.

Check out:

[parseFloat](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseFloat.asp)

[parseInt](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseInt.asp)

Comment: Thank you for the respective links.